# Data is not visible in lead when data are transfer from drupal 7 to sugarcrm 6.5.13(webform2sugar)

Tags: drupal, sugarcrm, drupal-webform

I want to transfer a data from drupal 7 to sugarcrm

**What I have Done**:- For that I used webform2sugar module and follow the tutorial

http://getlevelten.com/blog/david-hahn/basic-drupal-and-sugarcrm-integration-pt-1

I have done all things which mentioned in this tutorial .

**result**:- But data are not visible in lead of sugarcrm site.

Now I don`t know what can I do.

Answer (score 0):

follow these steps

content->addcontent->webform (create new febform)

manage field for newly create webform

1) add form component
2) click on sugarcrm  set Send to SugarCRM TRUE
3) add campaign ID of sugarcrm campaign
4) Add Sugar CRM Mapping to select webform field map with crm field

Comment: thanks rupesh  my problem is solved  data is not visible in lead due to http authentication.  Now I need data in account can you help me  how it is possible.

Comment: for capturing data in account i think need to call soap service of sugarcrm.